# Trying to implement Fusion Charts in xPages; chart not loading

Tags: xpages, fusioncharts

I am attempting to load fusion charts into an xPage. Following this tutorial http://docs.fusioncharts.com/tutorial-getting-started-your-first-charts-building-your-first-chart.html

The chart is not loading and is showing chart loading. At the bottom of the page I get a few error messages in the js console.

Here is the code I am using for the page. (url changed from actual url)

```
<xp:this.resources>


    <xp:script src="https://URL/Field/fplan.nsf/fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js"
        clientSide="true">
    </xp:script>
<xp:script
        src="https://URL/Field/fplan.nsf/fusioncharts/js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"
        clientSide="true">
    </xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:scriptBlock type="text/javascript">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
  FusionCharts.ready(function(){
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    "type": "column2d",
    "renderAt": "chartContainer",
    "width": "500",
    "height": "300",
    "dataFormat": "json",
    "dataSource":  {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Monthly revenue for last year",
        "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
        "xAxisName": "Month",
        "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
        "theme": "fint"
     },
     "data": [
        {
           "label": "Jan",
           "value": "420000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Feb",
           "value": "810000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Mar",
           "value": "720000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Apr",
           "value": "550000"
        },
        {
           "label": "May",
           "value": "910000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Jun",
           "value": "510000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Jul",
           "value": "680000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Aug",
           "value": "620000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Sep",
           "value": "610000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Oct",
           "value": "490000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Nov",
           "value": "900000"
        },
        {
           "label": "Dec",
           "value": "730000"
        }
      ]
  }

 });
  revenueChart.render();
})]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

<div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'desc' of undefined fusioncharts.js:436(anonymous function) fusioncharts.js:436v.core fusioncharts.js:20v.registrars.module fusioncharts.js:19v.extend.register fusioncharts.js:22(anonymous function) fusioncharts.js:236
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined fusioncharts.js:437(anonymous function) fusioncharts.js:437v.core fusioncharts.js:20v.registrars.module fusioncharts.js:19v.extend.register fusioncharts.js:22(anonymous function) fusioncharts.js:437
>   Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function fusioncharts.js:129(anonymous function) fusioncharts.js:129c fusioncharts.js:32H fusioncharts.js:32b.triggerEvent fusioncharts.js:36d.raiseEvent fusioncharts.js:36d.extend.render fusioncharts.js:70(anonymous function) chart.xsp:88(anonymous function)

If I drop an HTML file into the NSF as a file in the webcontent folder I am able to load the chart so at least I know the fusionchart files are sound.

Any assistance in how to implement this would be appreciated.

Comment: Does Fusioncharts use AMD? AMD loading does not work with Dojo in XPages.

Comment: From what I understand Fusioncharts is not AMD compatible. They recently changed from pure swf to pure js. Sean Cull has a blog posting on using them in the past. Didn't realize that AMD loading with xpages. good to know thanks.

Comment: I decided to go with jQuery.Gantt which works great in xpages.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would start by moving the chart initialization code into a client side script library and adding that as a resource to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Looks like adding the chart initialization into a client side library doesn't make any change.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the script in the following way:

```
<xp:this.resources>
<xp:headTag tagName="script">
<xp:this.attributes>
<xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
<xp:parameter name="src" value=
"https://URL/Field/fplan.nsf/fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js" />
</xp:this.attributes>
</xp:headTag>
<xp:headTag tagName="script">
<xp:this.attributes>
<xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
<xp:parameter name="src" value=
"https://URL/Field/fplan.nsf/fusioncharts/js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js" />
</xp:this.attributes>
</xp:headTag>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Comment: Did that work for you? I decided to switch over to an opensource gantt chart component which I was able to implement. Thank you for the response!